# Comma before "as well as" when making an aside

Tags: commas

I was wondering if the two sentences below are correct. Does the first sentence need a commas separating "and taking students on field trips," similar to how sentence two is structured? I read on https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20well%20as that commas would be used in sentence two. But is sentence one correct? Is sentence two improper because it doesn't intend the aside to be considered less important?

1. "Teaching civics classes is helpful to your school’s entire student population, but teaching those classes and taking students on field trips is even more helpful to your law school’s entire student population."

or

2. "Teaching civics classes is helpful to your school’s entire student population, but teaching those classes, as well as taking students on field trips, is even more helpful to your law school’s entire student population."

Answer (score 1):

**Sentence 1** does not need a comma.

If *teaching those classes and taking students on field trips* is one joint method, the sentence is correct as written:

> Teaching civics classes is helpful to your school’s entire student population, but teaching those classes and taking students on field trips is even more helpful to your law school’s entire student population.

Compare to a less complicated sentence with the same construction:

> Smiling and laughing is helpful to your health, but eating and breathing is even more beneficial to your body's success.

Clearly no need for commas.

However, if *teaching those classes* and *taking students on field trips* **are** two distinct activities to be included, you should have a plural **are** in place of your singluar **is**:

> Teaching civics classes is helpful to your school’s entire student population, but teaching those classes and taking students on field trips **are** even more helpful to your law school’s entire student population.

**Sentence 2** is acceptable either way, but as you note, using commas to isolate *as well as taking students on field trips* would indicate that it does not have the same importance as *teaching those classes* does.

See [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/as-well-as-comma/):

> Most of the time, you don’t need a comma before as well as. Using a comma turns the thing you’re talking about with as well as into an aside–information that’s less important than the rest of the sentence. That’s where the judgement call comes in. You have to decide whether the things you’re connecting with as well as are equally important or not.